# Why is help() function causing an ImportError?

Tags: python, function, types

I tried to run this code in order to check what a method can do in python:

```
print(dir(str))
print(help(str.upper))
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types' (/Users/aedrianlopez/Desktop/python_training/types.py)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python3 -u "/Users/aedrianlopez/Desktop/python_training/string_methodsz.py"]
[dir: /Users/aedrianlopez/Desktop/python_training]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

I'm using Python 3.9.2.

Comment: Looks like what you wrote relies on the `types` module but that's what you named your script so it's looking for what it needs in your script and failing.

Comment: Actually it looks like you have _a_ script named `types.py` that's in the same directory as the one you're running (and it's hiding the one in the standard-library).